# How to scale down retina image sprite with css

Tags: css, sprite, scaling

I have a problem loading retina images.
I have got two imagesprites. One normal and one retina.
The problem is that I don't know how to scale down the retina image, it is now twice the size.
This is my css.

```
.home {
    background: url('../images/buttonSprite.png') -49px -52px;
    width: 43px;
    height: 43px;
}
@media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    .home {
        background: url('../images/buttonSprite@2x.png') no-repeat -79px -113px !important;
        -webkit-background-size:43px 43px;
    }
}
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: This all depends on the size of the background image. A live situation or fiddle would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try just this:

```
.home {
    background: url('http://img580.imageshack.us/img580/9284/buttonsprite.png') no-repeat -49px -53px;
    width: 43px;
    height: 43px;
}

@media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), all and (-moz-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), all and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2), all and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
    .home {
        background: url('http://img90.imageshack.us/img90/5624/buttonsprite2x.png') no-repeat -39px -56px;
        background-size: 200px 496px;
    }
}
```

Notice that I used a pixel-ratio of 1.5, that's pretty much a standard. I also included the other prefixes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. unfortunately this doesn't work. Here is a example to see what i mean. http://tinkerbin.com/t9B6DZyZ @media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) is used as an example. I now ratio must be 2  Hopefully someone can help with this

Comment: thanks very much it works!. Didn't know i had to use the dimension of the whole image